# Why I am getting ModuleNotFoundError when I make an Exe file for tkinter GUI?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I have a simple code to use the LHS design of the experiment, and it works fine.

```
from tkinter import *
from pyDOE import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

n_points = IntVar()
n_features = IntVar()

label1 = Label(root, text="Initial No. sample points:")
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)

entry1 = Entry(root, textvariable=n_points)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)

label2 = Label(root, text="No. parameters:")
label2.grid(row=1, column=0)

entry2 = Entry(root, textvariable=n_features)
entry2.grid(row=1, column=1)

label3 = Label(root)
label3.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)

def LHS():
    lhs_design = lhs(n_features.get(), samples=n_points.get(), criterion="corr")
    label3.config(text="your design is:" + str(lhs_design))

mybutton = Button(root, text="Calculate!", command=LHS)
mybutton.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

I want to create an `Exe` file using `pyinstaller`. I follow these steps:

1. put `mycode.py` in a `folder`.
2. open `cmd`, and I change the directory to the `folder`
3. run `pyinstaller --onefile -w mycode.py`
4. Then in the created `dist` folder, there would be an `Exe` file

however, when I run the exe file, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mycode.py", line 2, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyDOE'
```

Am I making a mistake somewhere in the code that I have run in cmd? or do I need to add the `pyDOE` package somewhere in the exe file folder?

I also had the same problem in another post: [How to make an executable file when we are running an R script in python and Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71625209/how-to-make-an-executable-file-when-we-are-running-an-r-script-in-python-and-tki)

I was trying to run an `r` code in python, so I added this library: from `rpy2.robjects.packages import importr`, and I got similar error. I thaught,  the error might be because of reading from `r` but it seems I am making a mistake somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer for my post.

It seems it makes difference where to put `mycode.py` file and using the `pyinstaller`.

The file needs to be where your python is installed, in the `scripts folder`. Then, we can use `pyinstaller mycode.py`.